# mysql count rows from other table and use it in where

Tags: mysql, count, where-clause

I have a simple Query but actually no idea. I need a result from a subquery in `where` clause:

```
SELECT u.*,(SELECT COUNT(ur_id) FROM #__user_relation WHERE (uid1=u.u_id AND 
uid2='#me') or (uid2=u.u_id AND uid1='#me')) as count FROM #__user as u WHERE 
u.u_id!='me' AND count=0

Unknown column 'count' in 'where clause'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.*,(
SELECT COUNT(ur_id) 
FROM #__user_relation 
WHERE (uid1=u.u_id AND uid2='#me') or (uid2=u.u_id AND uid1='#me')) as count 
FROM #__user as u 
WHERE u.u_id!='me' **having count=0**
```